# Give a "name" to a network location in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ip

How can I assign a "name" to a network location in Windows 7? E.g.

```
"Test" 192.168.2.1
```

Comment: Do you mean a network share? Or a whole computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "name" of the computer with the IP 192.168.2.1 is its [hostname](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname). You have to set it on the computer with the IP 192.168.2.1. Here is a [HowTo](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-computer-name-in-windows-vista/) for Windows Vista/7.

If you want to just use that name on your machine to refer to 192.168.2.1, you can edit your [HOSTS-file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) and append the following line:

```
192.168.2.1 test
```